# How to resize QCheckBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcheckbox

The code below creates a single `Dialog` window with two `checkboxes`.
Second checkbox was constrained to a 8x8px size with `setMaximumSize(8, 8)` function.
But it appears that the smaller size of the checkbox widget was not applied to the cross icon. So the icon is clipped by the boundaries of the checkbox widget. How to make sure the cross icon is scaled proportionally with the checkbox widget?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

panel=QtGui.QDialog()
panel.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

checkbox1 = QtGui.QCheckBox()
panel.layout().addWidget(checkbox1)

checkbox2 = QtGui.QCheckBox()
checkbox2.setMaximumSize(8, 8)
panel.layout().addWidget(checkbox2)

panel.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is best to resize using the stylesheet:

```
{your QCheckbox}.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator { width: npx; height: mpx;}")
```

**Complete code:**

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    panel = QtGui.QDialog()
    panel.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

    checkbox1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("normal1")
    panel.layout().addWidget(checkbox1)

    checkbox2 = QtGui.QCheckBox("small")
    checkbox2.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox::indicator { width: 10px; height: 10px;}")
    panel.layout().addWidget(checkbox2)

    checkbox1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("normal2")
    panel.layout().addWidget(checkbox1)

    panel.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: When I do this, the checks stay the same size, but the box gets smaller.

Comment: @ErikAronesty What QStyle are you using ?, the geometrical characteristics depend on QStyle, try with `app.setStyle("fusion")`